# Unique users tracking with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, analytics

How to track unique users' stats per day with MongoDB?
My first idea was to use upsert with $addToSet (adding ip to ips array and then count array.length), but this method has restrictions (f.e. collection's size).

Answer (score 1):

If you shard it, I dont think you'll have any issues.

See [this link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits)